# What code design should I use in this case?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's suppose I have following code (two almostly similar methods is the API requirement):

```
method1() {
  ...
  internalMethod();
  ...
}

method2() {
  ...
  internalMethod();
  ...
}

internalMethod() {
  ...
  internalMethodHelper();
  ...
}

internalMethodHelper() { ... }
```

And suppose I need to add new one `method3()`, which implementation requires another signature for `internalMethod()` and `internalMethodHelper()`.

So, as I think, there is only one way to resolve this situation:

```
method1() {
  ...
  internalMethod(sign1);
  ...
}

method2() {
  ...
  internalMethod(sign1);
  ...
}

method3() {
  ...
  internalMethod(sign2);
  ...
}

internalMethod(sign1) {
  ...
  internalMethodHelper(sign1);
  ...
}

internalMethod(sign2) {
  ...
  internalMethodHelper(sign2);
  ...
}

internalMethodHelper(sign1) { ... }

internalMethodHelper(sign2) { ... }
```

Am I right ? Or it's a very bad code design to overload methods in this case?

Thanks for all of your answers!

Comment: At this level of detail almost nothing can be said. Overloading is a common and useful device.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with using helper and/or internal methods, the validity of which would be easier to reason about with *useful/relevant* method names and types (eg *actual* problematic code) - whether or not that applies in this case though, is hard to tell from the *fictitious example*. (That being said, I prefer to use the "Impl" prefix.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO **Method Overloading**  is not **Code Smell**. If your need is to overload method in this context then do it. *Design Patterns are tools not rules.* They should be used wisely & must not be forced.

Also, if you write new class & put that method in it then ask these questions to yourself.

- Does the new class does what it says?
- Does the method written in it do what it says?

If yes, then can **extract method** & put in other Type. Otherwise stick with overloading, there is nothing like bad design here.

Answer (score 2):

In this case [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) might 
help you.

It's better explained by [Strategy Design Pattern - GOF](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Strategy.aspx) that states:

> The strategy pattern is a design pattern that allows a set of similar algorithms to be defined and encapsulated in their own classes. The algorithm to be used for a particular purpose may then be selected at run-time according to your requirements.

The strategy pattern is used to create an **interchangeable family of algorithms** from which the required process is **chosen at run-time**.

This allows the behaviour of a program to change dynamically according to configuration details or user preferences.

It also *increases flexibility by allowing new algorithms* to be easily incorporated in the future.

[image]

Comment: The guy who asked this question worry about the method signature of implementation methods he used for method3(...). I know What's Strategy & where to use it. But in this situation what you're trying to do with Strategy Pattern?